# How to adjust Qt Creator for VTune Amplifier in Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu-12.04, intel-vtune

Intel VTune Amplifier does not show source code (only assembly) for C++ project from Qt Creator. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you've built the binary with -g compiler option (Linux), or /Zi /DEBUG (Windows). Also, if sources, binaries or symbol files were moved before profiling, configure Search directories in VTune project properties.